# How to calculate a reduced volume?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry, analytic-geometry, volume

Let's say we have an irregular 3D shape with **volume=V** ( we know V but we don't know its equation= F).  Now I want to calculate another 3D shape which is exactly the same shape but one size smaller, such that at any point of space, the smaller one has a **vertical distance=a** from the outer one.

[image]

Comment: You need more constraints to make the task sensible. Consider two easy "regular" shapes as an example. (1) Originally a sphere with volume $V$ and radius is larger than $a$, then clearly the reduced shape is the smaller sphere which volume is easy and finite. (2) Originally a cuboid of volume $V$ with one of its dimensions (side length) being $2a+\epsilon$, then the reduced shape can have vanishingly small volume with arbitrarily small $\epsilon$.